# Converting datetime arrays to timestamp Python

Tags: python, arrays, datetime

Bascially, I have an array of datetime that I want to convert into timestamp, but I'm stuck. Below is my Time array.

```
Time
Out[31]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 100000),
       datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 300000),
       datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 500000), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 19, 30, 0, 500000),
       datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 19, 30, 0, 700000),
       datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 19, 30, 0, 900000)], dtype=object)
```

I've tried

```
x = time.mktime(Time.timetuple())
```

but I get the error:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'timetuple'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you think the difference is between datetime and timestamp?

Comment: Isn't timestamp in the form of seconds that has passed since 1970/01/01 ?

Answer (score 1):

You could store the datetimes or the timestamps, which are just integers. Here the timestamps are calculated from the datetimes.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 100000)
>>> T = np.array([dt], dtype=np.datetime64)
>>> import time
>>> ts = int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
>>> T = np.array([ts], dtype=np.int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use **Time.timetuple()** because **Time** is a numpy array. You can just iterate over the array though, like this:

```
x = [time.mktime(t.timetuple()) for t in Time]
```